# Xml deserialization. Is it possible to save string format from xml?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xmlserializer

I am using `new XmlSerializer(typeof(R))` to get object from xml.

But I am facing a problem that attribute value in xml has some format, for example:

```
<dueNote value="Дата перевода валюты = 12.03.2020 18:31:58
Курс доллара к рублю = 71.472
Курс франка к рублю = 76.457
Курс евро к рублю = 81.0207
Тип расчетного расстояния = 2
"/>
```

Is it possible to somehow save the format of the xml attribute? Currently after deserialization this string becomes flat, without any newlines etc.

Is there any annotation like `'XmlAttrubte'` that responses for formatting?

Code:

```
[XmlElement("dueNote")]
public StringValueElement DueNote { get; set; }

public class StringValueElement
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public StringValueElement(object value)
    {
        Value = Convert.ToString(value);
    }

    public StringValueElement()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to the lack of a language tag, your question was left without much attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XML character entities to mark the end of line inside an attribute value

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dueNote value="Дата перевода валюты = 12.03.2020 18:31:58&#xA;
Курс доллара к рублю = 71.472&#xA;
Курс франка к рублю = 76.457&#xA;
Курс евро к рублю = 81.0207&#xA;
Тип расчетного расстояния = 2&#xA;
">
</dueNote>
```

The attribute value can only be plain text, not structured text, special characters need to be encoded as character entities.

Line breaks are allowed in XML attribute values, however according to W3C recommendation your XML parser should normalize the all whitespace characters to space (0x20).

http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#AVNormalize

Comment: I am receiving the response from foreign API, I can't add additional characters at the end of the attribute. Is there any way to resolve this problem using XmlReaderSettings ?

Comment: There is unfortunately no setting for handling this. The xml specification states that the parser should normalize line breaks to a space character. The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Most xml parsers normalize the contents of attributes by removing unnecessary spaces. But not all of them.

You can use [XmlTextReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader). It will leave the whitespaces as they are.

```
R root;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(R));

using (var reader = new XmlTextReader("test.xml")) // new XmlTextReader(stream);
{
    root = (R)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
Console.WriteLine(root.DueNote.Value);
```